# How to get page numbers only on the header?

Tags: fancyhdr

I've decided to use Latex for my thesis.
I need to follow some style directions such as having the page number on the upper right side, starting to print the numbers only from the second page of TOC and beyond.  Before that page the counter goes on but shouldn't print anything.

When I tried to do it with regular Latex commands I faced problems and decided to try fancyhdr, but the problem is the same:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside, spanish]{book}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=3.4cm, top=4.7cm, bottom=4.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[skip=12pt, indent=2em]{parskip}   
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}   
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}  
\usepackage[bottom,hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\setstretch{1.2}}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{5mm}
\usepackage{chngcntr}  
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage{appendix}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
\renewcommand{\restoreapp}{} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}    
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\title{''VERY LONG TITLE''}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}  
\fancyhead[RE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}  
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
         THIS is a THESIS
        \vspace{1cm}
        \large FACULTAD EN CIENCIAS DE LA SALUD,\\
        \vspace{2cm}
        \LARGE ``LONG TITLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE.''\\
        \tiny
        \vspace{1cm}
        \Large Autor: \\        
        \Large MR. X\\
\end{titlepage}

\newpage

\chapter*{}
\begin{flushright}
    \textit{Dedicado a mi familia}
\end{flushright}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\blindtext[1]

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures 
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables 

\chapter{Introducción}
\blindtext[1]
\section{Cosas interesantes}
\blindtext[1]
\subsection{Ámbito del estudio} 
\blindtext[1]
\chapter{Discusión}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{appendices} 
\chapter{Resumen procesos de limpieza y transformación de los datos}    
\blindtext[1]
\chapter{Código fuente}
\blindtext[1]    
\chapter{Artículo científico asociado a la tesis}
\blindtext[1]
\end{appendices}
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

Some page numbers appear on the header, some other on the footer, I don't know why.

[image]

I've also tried with local modifiers such as *\thispagestyle{empty}* but if the text of that section is long it seems to only affect the first page of that section.

Comment: This is because on pages with chapter titles, the page style is the plain style. If want page numbers also in the right header for these pages, you have to redefine the `plain` style. Do you want also want head rules on these pages?

Comment: I would like to have the number from the second page of the TOC and beyond. The head rules aren't important for me, the easier solution would be right, or the solution you suggest.

Comment: Your suggestion led to try 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[RE]{\thepage}
 \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} .
Now the numbers are OK but the head rules still appear on odd pages.

Comment: I've also tried to redefine the empy and plain styles but then the compilation lasts forever and crashes. The problem may be related with scyntex.

Comment: I have a simple solution, with no headrules at all. I'll try to see if an easier solution can be found with `titleps` to have headrules, except on the first page of chapters.

Comment: @Bernard Than you, I'm looking forward to seeing your solution.  A solution without fancyhdr nor any extra package would also be OK.  Or maybe replacing the titlepage blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `titleps`: I redefine  the `plain` style as the `empty` style if a boolean `all plain` is false, and as a style with the page number on the top right corner of the page, and  I define a `ruledplain` style, which adds a head rule. In addition, I load the `emptypage` package, which removes all footers and headers from empty pages.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, spanish]{book}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=3.4cm, top=4.7cm, bottom=4.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[skip=12pt, indent=2em]{parskip}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage[bottom,hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\setstretch{1.2}}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{5mm}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage{appendix}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
\renewcommand{\restoreapp}{}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\title{''VERY LONG TITLE''}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{allplain}

\usepackage{titleps}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\ifbool{allplain}{\sethead{}{}{\thepage}{}}{}%
}%
\newpagestyle{ruledplain}{%
\headrule
\sethead{}{}{\thepage}}%
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{titlepage}
         THIS is a THESIS
        \vspace{1cm}
        \large FACULTAD EN CIENCIAS DE LA SALUD,\\
        \vspace{2cm}
        \LARGE ``LONG TITLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE.''\\
        \tiny
        \vspace{1cm}
        \Large Autor: \\
        \Large MR. X\\
\end{titlepage}

\newpage

\chapter*{}
\begin{flushright}
    \textit{Dedicado a mi familia}
\end{flushright}
\lipsum

\chapter*{Abstract}
\blindtext[1]
\tableofcontents
\setbool{allplain}{true}
\pagestyle{ruledplain}
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables

\chapter{Introducción}
\blindtext[1]
\section{Cosas interesantes}
\blindtext[1]
\subsection{Ámbito del estudio}
\blindtext[1]
\chapter{Discusión}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Resumen procesos de limpieza y transformación de los datos}
\blindtext[1]
\chapter{Código fuente}
%\blindtext
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Artículo científico asociado a la tesis}
\blindtext[1]
\end{appendices}
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great.  It would be nice to get this things done just with LaTex.
Now it works. The numbering has been removed from all blank pages and the Abstract and Title pages.
And the numbering starts from the third page of my TOC (which has 3 pages).  How can I force it to start at the second TOC page?  It's a ridiculuos style specification of my university but I have to do it.

Comment: Mmmmm… For me, it starts at the second page of the toc. Could you post a minimal code reproducing the problem?

Comment: OK, just add \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}   and many new sections or subsections in order to get a 3 pages TOC.  Or maybe I can just start the numbering after the TOC.

Comment: No problem whatsoever.

Comment: How can I remove the header rule or the number on a single page?  For example I have several sidewaystables (floats) taking up a whole page (they exact placement is not decided by me, it's automatic).

Comment: Try `\thispagestyle{empty]`?